# how to simulate IgnoreRoute in my custom MvcRouteHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.NET MVC3 App I try simulate "routes.IgnoreRoute("...")"
I create CustomMvcRouteHandler:

```
public class CustomMvcRouteHandler: MvcRouteHandler
{        
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
         // do something
         ....
         return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

in my Global.asax.cs file i have:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // ............ 
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        // ............
     }


 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new CustomMvcRouteHandler();
     }
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean in your question, but I'll try to answer it...

To simulate an `IgnoreRoute` all you need to do is associate an instance of the `StopRoutingHandler` from your route. If you're using the built-in ASP.NET "Route" class then you would do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Ignore-This", // Route name
    "ignore/{this}/{pattern}" // URL with parameters
).RouteHandler = new StopRoutingHandler();
```

Anything that matches that pattern will cause the routing system to immediately stop processing any more routes.

If you want to write your own custom route (for example, a new route type that derives from `RouteBase`), then from its `GetRouteData` method you need to return the `StopRoutingHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

@Eilon is the correct answer.  Here is an alternative syntax that feels more MVCish.

```
routes.Add("Ignore-This",
    new Route(
        "ignore/{this}/{pattern}",
        new StopRoutingHandler())
);
```